# How to get list of all software installed using python quickly?

Tags: python, wmi

I want to have list of software installed on my system using python. Code looks as follows:

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI()
for p in w.Win32_Product():
    print r"\newcommand*{\Title}", "{" + p.Version +"}"
    print r"\newcommand*{\Title}", "{" + p.Vendor +"}"
    print r"\newcommand*{\Title}", "{" + p.Caption +"}"
    print("\hline")
```

Now, when i execute it i got an error in between its execution as:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

So on net i searched and got that such error is when you're trying to concatenate a string with something that is None. so, in my code i did following change to deal with it:

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI()
print "hello"
for p in w.Win32_Product():
    print r"\newcommand*{\Title}", "{" + p.Version +"}"
    print r"\newcommand*{\Title}", "{" + p.Vendor +"}"
    if p.Caption == "NoneType":
        pass
    else:
        print r"\newcommand*{\Title}", "{" + p.Caption +"}"
    print("\hline")
```

But still it shows the same error. How to resolve such error?
Also, i wanted to know is there some other way to have list of installed software quickly available with me because my code is taking very long to have the list avaialable.

Comment: Is this LaTeX output? Why redefine the `\Title` command at each line? Why not using `print r"\Title{" + p.XXX + "}"`?

Answer (score 3):

```
if p.Caption == "NoneType":
```

`p.Caption` is `None`, so its type is `NoneType`. You can check for `None` like this:

```
if p.Caption is None:
```

Or in your case, since you want to check whether it is not `None`, invert the condition:

```
if p.Caption is not None:
    print r"\newcommand*{\Title}", "{" + p.Caption +"}"
```

If that still shows the same error, then it’s not `p.Caption` what is `None` but `p.Version` or `p.Vendor` (or both), so if those properties are not guaranteed to contain a value, then check for them too.

An alternative to that, if you don’t care that there is output with “None” in it, is to use string formatting which is more powerful than string concatenation:

```
print r"\newcommand*{\Title}", "{%s}" % p.Caption
```

Answer (score 2):

You will find this is a common scenario in python.

**String Concatenating A NoneType**

You need to explicitly cast to a string like this:

`str(p.Version)`

`print r"\newcommand*{\Title}", "{" + str(p.Version) +"}"`

You can read more about the str() method in the official docs here: [str()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)

**Skipping a NoneType So Its Not Printed**

```
if p.Caption is not None:
    print r"\newcommand*{\Title}", "{" + str(p.Caption) +"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The correct way to check for `None` is `if a is None:`
2. You really should make a function for this and not to generate so awful spaghetti code.

Comment: I believe that your second point is a matter or preference. I would hardly consider a single conditional if/else to be generating `awful spaghetti code` :)

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about the [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), it will handle such type conversion for you (and can be much more powerfull).

```
import wmi

PATTERN = r"\newcommand*{{\Title}}{{{}}}"

w = wmi.WMI()
for p in w.Win32_Product():
    print PATTERN.format(p.Version)
    print PATTERN.format(p.Vendor)
    print PATTERN.format(p.Caption)
    print("\hline")
```

You might also want to change the pattern to `r"\Title{{{}}}"` since it makes no sense for this LaTeX output (I assume) to redefine the `Title` command at each line without printing anything.